# Comparing asymptotics to alternate series test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I am a bit confused when applying asymptotics:

Let's consider $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{1}{k}$. We know that it is convergent (alternate series test). However, if I apply asymptotics I get the following:
$$
(-1)^k\frac{1}{k}= O\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\implies \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{1}{k}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty O\left(\frac{1}{k}\right).
$$
The resulting series is no longer convergent although it has the same asymptotic behavior?! How does this fit together?

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: Please remember that Big-O just talks about upper bounds... and being bounded above by a divergent series doesn't mean you diverge.

Comment: @Alan, Yes you are right. It was a typo. Thanks for the remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have two series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}\quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}$$
and we know that $$a_{k} = \mathcal{O}(b_{k})\quad \text{as} \quad k\to\infty.$$
Remember that this means that there is some constant $M>0$ and some index $n$ such that $$|a_{k}|\leq M|b_{k}| \quad\text{for all } k\geq n.$$

Now, this is useful for determining convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$, but only in the case that we *already know* that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}$ converges *absolutely*.  Indeed, if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}$ converges then we can say that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{k}| = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}|a_{k}| + \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}|a_{k}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}|a_{k}| + M\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}|b_{k}| $$ which converges because $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}|b_{k}|$ is the tail of a convergent series.  However, if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|b_{k}|$ diverges, then all we've done is bound $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ above by a divergent series, which we know from the comparison test doesn't tell us anything about the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$.

Comment: just to make sure that I have understood the concept correctly, I have added a quick example. In the example I have assumed the $n_0$ to be sufficiently large. I would be happy if you could tell me if I have set up the example right :)

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^4}\cdots\right)(-1)^n\\\leq \underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(-1)^n}_{<\epsilon}+\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}(-1)^n}_{<\epsilon}+\sum\limits_{n=n_0 +1}^{\infty}O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right),$$as $\Big|(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^4}+\cdots\right)\Big|\leq M\cdot\Big|\frac{1}{n^3}\Big|$. Then:$$\cdots=2\epsilon+\sum\limits_{n=n_0 +1}^{\infty}O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)=2\epsilon+M\sum\limits_{n=n_0 +1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}=(2+M)\epsilon.$$